# How to set font in Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

When I load my workspace project in Eclipse Che, there does not appear to be an option to set the font type, size etc :

[image]

How to set font in Eclipse Che ?

Update :

'Colors and Fonts' is not available in preferences :

[image]

Comment: Try IDE->Apperance->Colors and Fonts

Comment: @Pranalee please see question update

Comment: I see. May be they don't allow much customization then. They are allowing to choose theme though. May be you can try to download another theme and edit it.